# Machine learning PhD Interview technical questions

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, career, linear-algebra

I'm Software Engineer who applied to grad school for Machine Learning/Computer Vision PhD and currently waiting for interview calls. I'm brushing up Linear algebra/ ML topics. What kind of technical questions do professors generally ask in Ph.D interviews ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it is very needed to be familiar with the concepts in pattern recognition and statistical learning. The concepts about distributions of features.

Answer (score 2):

In general, linear algebra and basic concepts in statistics (probability distributions, marginalization) and machine learning (you should be familiar with terns like Maximum-A-Posteriori estimation and Maximum-Likelihood-Estimation, maybe Markov chains and SVMs, neural-networks, etc.).

Best practice would be to find out who is interviewing you and than look at what courses he is leading and what papers he has published in recent years. He is most likely to ask specific question from his field of expertise and interests.